# How to rename a bookmark in Safari on Mac (when the bookmark is loaded on page)?

Tags: mac, safari

As a Safari/Mac user...How can I tell what bookmark is loaded in the browser...So that I can rename the bookmark?

Similar to what Chrome offers?

1. Cmd-D: Save bookmark "Joes Cafe"
2. Browse stuff on amazon.com
3. Decide to load "Joes Cafe" from the bookmark
4. "Joes Cafe" loads in Chrome
5. Decided I want to rename the bookmark
6. CMD-D: Rename bookmark to "JoeyG's Cafe"

Comment: [[1]] Copy the address , go to "Show/View all BookMarks" , Paste into the SearchBox , the list of matching results will be available which you can select & rename ! [[2]] You might also make a new BookMark with the same address with a new "Correct" Name !